# YII2 gridview custom search with ajax

Tags: ajax, search, gridview, yii2

I am working with Yii2.0 search functionality,if we show the grid as its means the ajax search is working fine,but i have to changed the layout(see the screen below), from that right side form i have to do the search using ajax.

I also search with google but not get the related one.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you the use of a separated filter form  like explain in this Yii2 guide 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#separate-filter-form

Using  a partial view _search.php with (eg:) the following contents:

> ```
> <?php
>
>  use yii\helpers\Html;
>  use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
>
> ?>
>
>  <div class="post-search">
>     <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
>       'action' => ['index'],
>       'method' => 'get',
>    ]); ?>
>
>   <?= $form->field($model, 'title') ?>
>
>   <?= $form->field($model, 'creation_date') ?>
>
>   <div class="form-group">
>     <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
>     <?= Html::submitButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
>   </div>
>
>   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
> </div>
> ```
>
> and include it in index.php view like so:
>
> ```
> <?= $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]) ?>
> ```